# inotifywait with Docker command and variable

Tags: shell, ubuntu, docker, inotifywait

I am trying to create a shell script that will check for a new file then cp to a Docker Container. The code I have so far is...

```
#!/bin/sh


source="/var/www/html/"
dest="dev_ubuntu:/var/www/html/"

inotifywait -m "/var/www/html" -e create -e moved_to |
while read file; do
    sudo docker cp /var/www/html/$file dev_ubuntu:/var/www/html
done
```

But this code gives the following error:

```
Setting up watches.
Watches established.
"docker cp" requires exactly 2 argument(s).
See 'docker cp --help'.

Usage:  docker cp [OPTIONS] CONTAINER:SRC_PATH DEST_PATH|-
docker cp [OPTIONS] SRC_PATH|- CONTAINER:DEST_PATH

Copy files/folders between a container and the local filesystem
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have spaces in your file names? Use double quotes to avoid separating filenames by words:

```
echo $file
sudo docker cp "$file" dev_ubuntu:"$file"
```

I've also echoed the file name to see what is happening.

Comment: Name of file did have a space, I added a "_" for the space. and changed the code to                                                                                                           `sudo docker cp "/var/www/html/$file" dev_ubuntu:/var/www/html` now I get the following error `lstat /var/www/html/var: no such file or directory`

Comment: With this you want to avoid docker volumes, right? Because volumes are intended to your use case

Comment: You're welcome. I have added double quotes to the second $file too

Comment: this one also works: `#!/bin/sh
MONITORDIR="/var/www/html/"
inotifywait -m -r -e create --format '%w%f' "${MONITORDIR}" | while read NEWFILE
do
        echo "File ${NEWFILE} has been created TEST"
        sudo docker cp ${NEWFILE} dev_ubuntu:/var/www/html
done`

Comment: Great. And why you don't use docker volume?

Comment: added quotes to ${NEWFILE} allows for spaced filenames `sudo docker cp "${NEWFILE}" dev_ubuntu:/var/www/html`